Implicit function parameter conversion not happening
I have the following piece of code:
template<class A>
struct X {
        template<class T>
        X(T t) {}
};

template<class A>
void f(X<A> x, A a) {}

int main() {
        f(0, 0);
}

which fails to compile (gcc 14.1.1) with the following error:
test.cc:20:10: error: no matching function for call to ‘f(int, int)’
   20 |         f(0, 0);
      |         ~^~~~~~
test.cc:17:6: note: candidate: ‘template<class A> void f(X<A>, A)’
   17 | void f(X<A> x, A a) {}
      |      ^
test.cc:17:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cc:20:10: note:   mismatched types ‘X<A>’ and ‘int’
   20 |         f(0, 0);
      |         ~^~~~~~

If I understand correctly, any value should be convertible to X<A> because of the templated constructor X(T)
What's interesting though is that the static_assert doesn't cause a compile-time error:
static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<int, X<int>>); // no assertion failure

How can I change the program to keep both templates and allow conversions to X?

You can't deduce A in X<A> from 0. What you can do it to disable deduction for X<A> using a standard trick: void foo(std::type_identity_t<X<A>> x, A a).

Questions are for questions, not solutions. Solutions fall under the "answer" category. You can answer your own question.

Implicit conversions are not considered during template argument deduction.

This is template type deduction, and it will not try to deduce a type which your input is convertible to.
A simpler example shows the problem, and also shows why it is a problem:
#include <type_traits>

struct Foo {};

template<typename T>
struct Bar {
    Bar(Foo);
};

template<class A>
void f(Bar<A>) {}

int main() {
    static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<Foo, Bar<int>>);
    static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<Foo, Bar<double>>);
    f(Foo{});
}

How can the compiler deduce A? It could be int, double, or anything else, as Bar<whatever> is convertible to Foo anyway.

Back to your case, you say that
    static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<int, X<int>>); // no assertion failure

Yes, but this passes too:
    static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<int, X<double>>); // no assertion failure

so why should the compiler deduce int instead of double?
You might think that the compiler can be 100% sure of A being int by doing argument deduction on the second argument, and so be happy with X<int> for the first parameter type. That's not possible because the deduction happens independently for every arg-param pair.

If a compiler can't deduce A from X<A>, why doesn't it simply ignore this failure ("deduction failure is not an error") and not deduce A to int from the second argument?

I'm think of specializations of X. That would create a problem, I think. I'll give a look at a book.

@Evg, and I understand correctly, each arg-param pair is analysed in isolation.
